# Instantiate an OpenShift service catalog template using the oc command line client

Tags: command-line, openshift

OpenShift offers a service catalog where I can choose certain applications from (e.g. CakePHP + MySQL) to deploy them on the cluster. As per my understanding, these are so-called templates. I already know how to deploy it via the Web console.

However, I´m wondering if it is possible to do so via the command line using *oc ...*
I was not able to find documentation on that topic. Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for creating objects from an existing template can be found in the [Generating a List of Objects](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#generating-a-list-of-objects) section of the [Templates](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/templates.html) page of the OKD/OpenShift documentation.

If the template is already available to the current project you can use the following oc command to instantiate objects from it:

```
$ oc process <template> | oc create -f -
```

If you need to pass parameters

```
oc process <template> -p PARAMETER_ONE=bob -p PARAMETER_TWO=mydatabase | oc create -f -
```

Alternately you can use the `oc new-app` command documented in the [Specifying a Template](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/new_app.html#specifying-a-template) section of the [Creating New Applications](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/new_app.html) page of the documentation.

```
$ oc create -f examples/sample-app/application-template-stibuild.json
$ oc new-app ruby-helloworld-sample
```

Comment: Hi @Nick,
thank you very much, but that is not quite the thing I was looking for. I know how to generate objects out of templates, but how can I specify the templates from the default OpenShift catalog here? In other words: What can I use for <template>?

Comment: It should be available via `oc new-app`. Try `oc new-app -L` to see everything available